# Android application with phonegap

Tags: android, html, animation, cordova

I have developed a application using Phonegap. HTML is created using HYPE. Functionality wise the application works well. The problem I am facing is, the application is too slow with animations. I have done enough search on google but it didn't solve my problem. What should I do now to get a smoother animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it running to slow on the actual device (which one) or in the emulator?

You can try to do some profiling. If not already done, try to encapsulate the frontend code, so you can test in a desktop Webbrowser. Then you can do some performance tests in i.e. Firebug

Comment: I have checked with both device and emulator. Its working fine in ipad and desktop browsers. Can you give some important things to be considered while profiling?

Comment: If you do this in firebug, go to the 'Console' tab and click on 'Profile'. Then use your application heavily, especially the parts you consider slow. Click 'profile' again and analyze, which parts are the bottleneck. Try to optimize them, if you can, otherwise post the problematic parts here to get help.